# relativeURL.replace is not a function error in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js

Why do I get this error in my Next.js app?

> TypeError: relativeURL.replace is not a function. (In
> 'relativeURL.replace(/^/+/, '')', 'relativeURL.replace' is undefined)

`Request.js` file

```
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY

const requests = {
  fetchTrending: {
    title: 'Trending',
    url: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
  },
}

export default requests
```

`axios.js` file

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
})

export default instance
```

`Banner.js` file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { InformationCircleIcon, PlayIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'
import axios from '../axios'
import requests from '../Requests'
import Image from 'next/image'

function Banner() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get(requests.fetchTrending)
      setMovie(
        request.data.results[
          Math.floor(Math.random() * request.data.results.length - 1)
        ]
      )
      return request
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  console.log(movie)

  function truncate(string, n) {
    return string?.length > n ? string.substring(0, n - 1) + '...' : string
  }

  return (
    <header className="relative h-[100vh] w-[100vw] bg-black">
      <div className="relative z-50 ml-10 h-[190px] pt-10">
        <Image
          src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie?.backdrop_path}`}
          layout="fill"
          objectFit="contain"
          objectPosition="left"
        />
 </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: I believe this is caused by your use of axios and have nothing to do with Next.js.  The method `axios.get` only takes string as the first argument, try `await axios.get(requests.fetchTrending.url)`.

Comment: @hangindev.com Thanks the error disappeared. But now in console it shows "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401"

Comment: Now Axios is performing what it is supposed to do. The usage of TMDB API (I assumed) is out of scope, check out [its documentation](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/status-codes).

Answer (score 0):

try this code in Bannner.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import instance from './axios';

function Banner(props) {
    const [movies, setmovies] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
          try {
            const req = await instance.get(props.fectUrl);
            setmovies(req.data.results)
            return console.log(req.data.results);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Axios Error:", error);
          }
        }
    
        fetchData();
      }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

export default Banner

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).